# Compilation error when trying to build a maven project with JAVA custom annotation which has ENUM variables defined in it

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, enums

I have few custom java Annotations present in the parent project which successfully builds.
When trying to build the test project which has the class "TestClass" using maven 3.x.x, it throws compilation error:
**[ERROR] /C:/Users/.../TestClass.java:[31,1] annotation com.xxx.annotation.CustomAnnotation is missing value for the attribute < clinit >**

Points to Note:

- If I remove the ENUM or replace it with a String, it compiles properly.
- Eclipse does not throw any compilation error whatsoever and builds and runs happily.

**Annotation Example: (I have changed the names for confidentiality)**

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@ABCD(abcd = "value")       
public @interface CustomAnnotation {
   String value();  
   final String xxx = "xxxyyyzzz";
   final EnumA enumA = EnumA.XXX;
   final EnumB enumB = EnumB.YYY;
}
```

**Class Example (I have changed the names for confidentiality):**

```
@CustomAnnotation("testclass")
public class TestClass {
   ...
   ...
   ...
 }
```

Did anybody come across such scenarios? Any suggestions?

Comment: Take a look here:
https://forums.oracle.com/message/4827054

Comment: Thanks Brian. I went through the post. Ofcourse there is no concrete reason as to why it might be happening every time I build it using maven(command line) and never shows up in eclipse(uses m2e). Although,there is 1 reply which says it is not recommended to declare fields(eg. EnumA enumA=EnumA.XXX) in annotation/interface? Why would it not be recommended? Since there is already an annotation,let it do the job rather than creating a final class and storing the info in it. I am basically accessing fields statically in many places eg.CustomAnnotation.xxx. Thanks in advance for your views on this

Comment: It's generally not recommended because it can lead to a lot of bloat in your interfaces. It sort of fits into the 1-feature-1-function idea: that interfaces are meant to define functionality and to lay out the interface contract. Annotations, more specifically, should be used to define meta properties of the code that it's annotating. Again, constants don't really help with that. You're right that the other option involves creating a fully-static, final class, but this isn't horrible.

Comment: Yeah. I have decided to go with final classes for all that static info and kept aside the annotations to do the job it is best for.

Answer (score 4):

upgrade **jdk** version to **1.7.80**. I observed same issue in version **1.7.79**.